# что не так в этом коде?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for n in range(40,100):

    a = '>' + '0' * n
    while '>1' in a or '>2' in a or '>0' in a:
        if '>1' in a:
            a = a.replace('>1', '22>', 1)

        if '>2' in a:
            a = a.replace('>2', '00>', 1)

        if '>0' in a:
            a = a.replace('>0', '11>', 1)

a = a.replace('>','1',1)
d = 0
for x in a:
    d += int(x)
if d == 77:
    print(n)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в этом коде что-то не так?

Comment: потому что у меня он не работает или выдает неправильный ответ

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он у вас не работает или выдает неправильный ответ?

Comment: потому что по задаче ответ правильный это 46 , а у меня выходит Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: извините если прям примитивные и тупые вопросы задаю, просто недавно только начала изучать python

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код запускается и завершает свою работу без ошибки.

Comment: значение чего должно быть 46?

Answer (score 0):

Это хорошие новости! Это означает, что в вашем коде нет ошибки. Вы прошли его правильно, и в этом нет ничего плохого. Pycharm возвращает 0, когда не находит ошибок (плюс любой вывод, который вы ему даете), и возвращает 1, а также сообщение об ошибке, когда обнаруживает ошибки.

Редакторы и скрипты ведут себя не так, как интерактивный терминал, когда вы запускаете функцию, она автоматически не показывает результат. Вы должны на самом деле сказать ему, чтобы сделать это самостоятельно.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).